# Derivative of $g(x) = f(\arccos(2x+3))$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

The exercise tells me that $f$ is a diferentiable function in $\Bbb R$ (and nothing else about it). It is asked to determine the derivative of $g$ and the domain of that derivative:

$$g(x) = f(\arccos(2x+3))$$
I am studying for a math test to go to university and am completly stuck on this exercise for over an hour, could someone help on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi, did you try using the chain rule?

Comment: the furthest i have been able to go is to get it to make a derivative of what is inside multiplied by the f'(arccos(2x+3)) but i can't determine any domain from that because i don't know the function f. am i missing something here?

Comment: @RubenGaspar Hint: what is the domain of arccos$(x)$?

Comment: I think you are supposed to assume the domain of $f$ is simply $\mathbb R$ so you just need to find the domain of $\arccos(2x+3)$.

Comment: Thank you all. I was totally ignoring the domain of arccos(x) and thinking that if f(x) was cos(x) it would just not work but that is just stupid from me. thank you so much for the help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : $$g’ (x)= f’ ( \arccos(2x+3))$$

Step 2 : Through chain rule differentiate inner function

$$=\frac{d}{dx}(\arccos(2x+3))$$

$$=- \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(2x+3)^2}} \ \frac{d}{dx}(2x+3)  $$

$$= - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x+3)^2}}$$

Final step: $$g’ (x)= f’ ( \arccos(2x+3)) = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x+3)^2}} $$